Grub rescue mode after formatting Linux Mint partition
I wanted to remove Linux Mint and replace the space left after by extending Ubuntu into it, and so I did through Windows 10. I believe that lead me to mess up big time as I can't edit Linux partitions from Windows.
These are the partitions I have.
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos7)
Out of these, only (hd0,msdos5) says it exists.

Your Linux Mint system was likely controlling the boot process (usually the last installed OS controls that), where you should have ensured another OS (not being deleted) controlled booting as a deleted OS cannot. What do you mean you're unable to use a temporary Ubuntu instance? as your question appears mostly to be about off-topic Linux Mint and Windows.

did you remove grub or UEFI partition? Then boot from a live session and fix your grub/UEFI https://www.shellhacks.com/reinstall-grub-from-live-usb-uefi-lvm/  or one of these https://www.baeldung.com/linux/grub-efi-reinstall

If you used Windows tools to edit Linux partitions, I would think your install is toast.

UPDATE: I finally fixed it after a bunch of troubleshooting! In my very specific case, I had three OS': Windows 10, Linux Mint and Ubuntu. Ubuntu wasn't working properly, so after updating Linux Mint and it not working, I tried using Windows 10 (very bad mistake) to delete Linux Mint, the partition with ROOT at the moment (worst mistake possible) and expand Ubuntu's partition to free up space (also very bad mistake, would've corrupted it horribly in the best case scenario). After trying to modify Ubuntu partitions and it not working, I rebooted and got the GRUB rescue mode screen. Oh no! So, long story short all I really needed to do was reinstall GRUB, but I needed root permission and Ubuntu would've been the best one to do that through. To reach Ubuntu, I used a live version of Linux Mint to install it back into the PC (it had trouble installing GRUB, so I had to use Ubuntu for that) and moved some files to a general archive. That in turn ended up making Ubuntu run again, only through a systemrescue Linux USB because GRUB was dead. From Ubuntu, I installed grub back into the PC, and then set it up to recognize all the other OS'.
TL;DR: The answer to all this was sysrecue and live versions in a USB and some troubleshooting.
Thank you for the helpful replies as they also helped me figure it all out.
